# Given any $a,b,c \geq 1$, prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 2a\sqrt{b-1} + 2b\sqrt{c-1} + 2c\sqrt{a-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, inequality, functional-inequalities

Given any $a,b,c \geq 1$, prove that:

$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 2a\sqrt{b-1} + 2b\sqrt{c-1} + 2c\sqrt{a-1}$

I tried using most of the popular inequalities and I didn't end up anywhere. Can anyone guide me through this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$RHS^2 \leq (4a^2+4b^2+4c^2)(a+b+c-3)$, so it suffices to show $a+b+c -3 \leq \frac{1}{4}(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Thank you! Your response really helped me understand the problem properly.

Comment: oh sorry, I should have known this better... I'll bear this in mind next time.

Comment: @David399, you're welcome, guess we have to read carefully the policy next time :).

Comment: You're absolutely right! I will take care of the way I write my question next time.